# Is it possible to read various differnt languages from JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, localization, jtextfield

I am trying to read string from JTextField, as long as string is in english, Everything works fine. But if I change it to Korean or Japanese I am getting all some fuzzy characters in the string. 
       Is there a way that I can read those string in the given language ?

For Example
    JTextField contains : 할로윈 빅 세일 마지막날입니다!
     And String read is : ??? ? ?? ???????!

Comment: If you happen to use Eclipse, there is a strange issue that text printed in console will be displayed incorrectly, unless your ***source file*** in encoded in say UTF-8. The actual strings are probably OK, but Eclipse seems to be using wrong encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check that the font you use to debug the content of the String actually supports those characters? Most coding or UI fonts do not support more than European characters.

You could try to encode the String as UTF-8 to actually check the bytes in the debugger using "getBytes" or by writing the String into an UTF-8 file.

Comment: @SumitLonkar: println will tell you nothing and will not work unless the console allows for the proper charset.

Comment: Thanks you guys for responses. Ended up using UTF-8 encoding to write to the file.

Comment: @SumitLonkar: If you ended up, maybe it is a good time to actually accept this answer?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the right encoding and a proper IDE.

[image]

When debbuging in IntelliJ using UTF-8 encoding:

[image: Debug in IntelliJ]

The code snippet I used:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class I18n {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("i18n");
                I18nView view = new I18nView();
                frame.getContentPane().add(view);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 150));
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    static class I18nView extends JPanel {
        private String i18n = " 할로윈 빅 세일 마지막날입니다!";
        private JTextField i18nTextField;

        I18nView() {
            createComponents();
            makeLayout();
            test();
        }


        private void createComponents() {
            i18nTextField = new JTextField(i18n);
        }
        private void makeLayout() {
            add(i18nTextField);
        }

        private void test() {
            String another = i18nTextField.getText();
            System.out.println("another = " + another);
        }

    }
}
```